# How do I compose a list of `Futures`?

Tags: scala, future

I have a collection of `Promises`. I was looking for an effective way to compose the resulting `Futures`. Currently the cleanest way i found to combine them was to use a scalaz `Monoid`, like so:

```
  val promises = List(Promise[Unit], Promise[Unit], Promise[Unit])

  promises.map(_.future).reduce(_ |+| _).onSuccess {
    case a => println(a)
  }  

  promises.foreach(_.success(()))
```

Is there a clean way to do this that doesn't require scalaz?

The number of `Futures` in the collection will vary, and lots of intermediate collections is undesirable.

Comment: Would you mind to aggregate `Futures` instead of `Promises`?

Comment: That is what im doing here, i extract the futures with .map()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Future.traverse`:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, Promise }

val promises = List(Promise[Unit], Promise[Unit], Promise[Unit])
Future.traverse(promises)(_.future)
```

This will give you a `Future[List[Unit]]`, which doesn't exactly qualify as "lots of intermediate collections", but isn't necessarily ideal, either. `Future.reduce` also works:

```
Future.reduce(promises.map(_.future))((_, _) => ())
```

This returns a `Future[Unit]` that will be satisfied when all of the futures are satisfied.

Comment: Given that it builds a collection, i wonder if the monoid is more efficient. But thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for -- apparently i dont know how to use the API docs as i never clicked on the Object version of Future.

Comment: `reduce` doesn't create a collection, so it should be at least as efficient as the monoid (probably more so).

Comment: Yes, well im using reduce in my example above, faster or not would depend on what you replaced `|+|` with. The traverse creates a list, so i think that may introduce some small overhead. I only have a handful of futures so the list is short and it probably doesnt matter.

Comment: You're using `reduce` on `List`, which is different from the one on `Future`, but right, the differences probably don't matter.

Comment: I created a list of a million double promises, and timed completing them with both techniques and traverse+sum is about 20% faster than reduce+monoid -- i think its something to do with the two levels of indirection (it has to compose the future and double monoids).

Comment: What about `Future.reduce`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e213624825748a120a6d  -- results in average milliseconds to process collection of promises: `Map(Monoid.append -> 895.3, Future.traverse -> 240.7, Future.reduce -> 284.4, Future.sequence -> 244.2)`

Answer (score 3):

`Future.sequence` is the method you want.

Comment: `Future.traverse` probably makes a little more sense (see my answer), but still creates at least one unnecessary intermediate collection.

Comment: Sequence simplifies traverse, so you're both right but i could only accept one. Sorry.

Comment: In this case `traverse` is actually both simpler and more efficient—it combines the necessary `map` and the `sequence` into a single operation.

Comment: They are almost equal, per the really crappy benchmark i did above.